# React.js rechart not showing data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, recharts

complete code at https://pastebin.com/EymDdLHk

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/animals/animal/client?clientId=" + user.id, {
        method: "get",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": `${token}`,
        },
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {
                var mydata = (result[0].peso)
                data.push(mydata)
                // var isArray = Array.isArray(data);


            },
            (error) => {
                setIsLoaded(true);
                setError(error);
            }
        )


}, [])
```

chart

```
 <LineChart
            width={650}
            height={300}
            data={data}
            margin={{
                top: 20,
                right: 50,
                left: 50,
                bottom: 70
            }}
        >
            <CartesianGrid vertical={false} />
            <XAxis dataKey='data' axisLine={false} tickLine={false} tickMargin={10} color={'#494949'} fontWeight={'500'} />
            <YAxis dataKey='peso' domain={['dataMin', 'dataMax']} tickCount={4} axisLine={false} tickLine={false} tickMargin={10} color={'#494949'} fontWeight={'500'} />
            <Tooltip />

            <Line
                type="monotone"
                dataKey="peso"
                stroke="#000000"
                activeDot={{ r: 8 }}
            />
        </LineChart>
```

i fetched my data from my api and after that i pushed my data into a variable array and used on my chart but it seems that isnt working because my chart is empty

here is my console.log [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uccCF.png)

anyone can help me?

Comment: use `state` to hold the fetched data , consider it be an empty array on initialization and later set the `state` ... can you add a working example ? like code sandbox

Comment: You can see a simple https://hoanguyenit.com/restful-api-using-react.html